# While loop not iterating

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, increment

Everything is correct but what's going on in my while loop.
I'm trying to write this function recursively, and this is what i've come up with.

```
def fp(f, guess, error=0.0000000000001):
    p_guess = guess
    c_guess = f(p_guess)
    iterations = 0
    while not close(p_guess, c_guess, error=error):
        next = f(guess)
        iterations += 1
        return fp(f, next, error=error)
    return (iterations, c_guess)

def fp_sqrt(x):
    return fp(lambda y: (y + x/y)/2, 1.0)
```

I know I'm missing something. Someone told me to take the return statement out of the scope from the while loop, but that just made an infinite loop.

From shell:

> > > fp_sqrt(2)

Expected output:
(5, 1.414213562373095)

My output:
(0, 1.414213562373095)
So the variable isn't incrementing to show how many iterations i went through in the loop.

Comment: If I take it out of the scope, wouldn't I have two return statements? isnt' that a problem?

Comment: The code seems somewhat confused. Either do something recursive or use a loop. Don't try to use both. If recursive, it should be function calls that you are trying to count -- not loop iterations.

Comment: sorry about that, the assignment wants to just edit code inside the while loop and not change anything else. this is what I've come up with, but yeah... is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: To answer your original question: recursion stops when `p_guess` and `c_guess` are close (whatever it means). In this case, the `while` loop makes zero iterations. The value of `iterations`, which is set to 0 before the loop, is not changed and is returned all the way to the caller.

Comment: your post is missing close(), you can start to debug by adding print statement(s) inside the loop, at function start/stop, or try running it in http://pythontutor.com/

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you are trying to do. What is the point of the recursion? Recursion is an *alternative* to loop-based iteration. You terminate the while loop in its first pass so your while loop might as well not be there -- or the recursion might as well not be there.

Comment: def close(x, y, error = 0.0000001):
        return abs(x - y) < error

Comment: Ok, I now know that, recursion and loops don't go hand in hand, so i shouldn't solve this with recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not resolve this with recursion but just by iterating and reassigning the results back to the loop variables, e.g.:

```
while not close(p_guess, c_guess, error=error):
    p_guess, c_guess = c_guess, f(c_guess)
    iterations += 1
return iterations, c_guess

#fp_sqrt(2) -> (5, 1.414213562373095)
```

Note: `next` is a builtin and you shouldn't use it as a variable name

You could have made this recursive but it makes the `while` just a verbose `if` statement:

```
while not close(p_guess, c_guess, error=error):  # if would suffice
    iterations, result = fp(f, c_guess, error=error)
    return iterations+1, result
return (0, c_guess)

#fp_sqrt(2) -> (5, 1.414213562373095)
```

Comment: thank you, the other functions i did were all done by recursion, so i guess my mind was overthinking it

Comment: i'm relatively new to python and i've never seen something like that done in one line. is it another way of saying p_guess = c_guess  & c_guess = f(c_guess)??

Comment: Yes equivalent to the two lines, `p_guess = c_guess; c_guess = f(c_guess)`. It's a standard tuple assignment and unpack and commonly used, e.g. swapping values is `a, b = b, a` that avoids the need of a temporary variable.